# No errors on Node console but unable to fetch data by Id - MERN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am struggling to find out where I am going wrong as I am getting no error messages, however my route/controller not working with a specific id.

This is my controller

```
module.exports = getUserById = (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.userId)
      .then(function (getUser) {
        res.send(getUser);
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        res
          .status()
          .res.json(err, { message: "successfully fetched user by id " })
      );
  };
```

This is my route

```
app
    .route("/api-users/:userId")
    .get((req, res, next) => {
      console.log(`Request from: ${req.originalUrl}`);
      console.log(`Request type: ${req.method}`);
      next();
    }, getUserById)
    // .get((req, res) =>
    //   res.send("/api-users/:userId GET- get user by Id request successful!")
    // )
```

This is my schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = UserModel = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    default: "Jane or John",
    required: false,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    default: "Doe",
    required: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    default: "email@email.com",
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1234,
    required: false,
  },
  created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

This is my server code

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

// bring in dotenv files for config of DB
require('dotenv').config();

// express app and port set up
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// file paths for static files
const path = require('path');

// Site security
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

// middleware executed in the order that they are described
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
const rateLimiter = new rateLimit({
  windowsMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 100,
  delayMs: 0,
});

// serve static files
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(204));

// test home route - routes stack after the static files
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('your app home route is working');
});

// import other routes
const crmRoutes = require('./apis/routes-config/crmRoutes');
crmRoutes(app);

// mongoDb setup
const dBurl = process.env.DB_CONNECTION;
mongoose.connect(
  dBurl,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  (error) => {
    if (!error) {
      console.log('mongo-db connection working');
    } else {
      console.log('check mongo-db connection', error);
    }
  }
);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`your-app listening on ${PORT}`));
```

I tested the route without data so the end point is working.

I am able to fetch all the data on my get route http://localhost:5000/api-users

```
[{"firstName":"Freddy","lastName":"Mercury","email":"freddy@mercury.com","phone":12345,"_id":"5f48fb1cebd188108ad4ad0b","created_date":"2020-08-28T12:39:56.732Z","__v":0},{"firstName":"Nat","lastName":"KingCole","email":"Nat@kingcole.com","phone":12345678,"_id":"5f48fb5debd188108ad4ad0c","created_date":"2020-08-28T12:41:01.938Z","__v":0},{"firstName":"Nikhil","lastName":"Banerjee","email":"Nikhil@Banerjee.com","phone":1234512345,"_id":"5f48fca56fd94110e9a21f62","created_date":"2020-08-28T12:46:29.322Z","__v":0}
```

When I tested my users with http://localhost:5000/api-users/1 on Postman it worked and having populated the database, when I try the route

http://localhost:5000/api-users/5f48fb1cebd188108ad4ad0b

I get the whole list of users. So I logged the get request to see if there was a challenge with the middleware (Mongoose - package json "mongoose": "^5.10.1")

In my node console I am seeing that the right request is being sent and no errors

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
your-app listening on 5000
mongo-db connection working
Request from: /api-users/5f48fb1cebd188108ad4ad0b
Request type: GET
```

When I go to postman or the url in google chrome I get all the data back not the data with the Id, on Postman I get 200-OK and then all the data.

I not sure how to debug this and fix - the DB is MongoDB and I am connected via Compass to the DB collection - so if I am getting all the data it does not appear to be the connection.

In this edit I have added more code as suggested - also I have tried downgrading to mongoose@4.7.2 as suggested - this does not work, moreover, the way I connect mongoDB works only with mongoose@5 and and above. This is a bug that has been reported on a GitHub repo, but it seems to have been closed without any solution offered. What I understand is the get route (generic) is already called and conflicts with the getId routes.
However explicitly calling `next()` or `end()` and adding the objectId as a string in my mongoose schema have also not worked.

All suggestions welcome! Many thanks. I have also shared the code on the GitHub repo for clarification from the collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
User.findById(req.params.userId, function (err, user) { 
      if(err){
         res.status(400).send(err);
      }
      res.status(200).send(user);
 });
```

Comment: Hi Deep that is what I tried first - as the nested call-backs in one of the stack-overflow threads suggested this. There are 2 things that happen and I am not able to figure this out - the id routes conflict with the generic routes. I am not sure how to get them both to work with mongoose. Downgrading to a lower version did not change anything for me although this was suggested in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is your Id is not reaching your findById function call or some other function is getting called by another route.
Do add console.log on the route and getUserById function.

```
module.exports = getUserById = (req, res) => {
console.log(req.params.userId); // to check the id
User.findById(req.params.userId)
  .then(function (getUser) {
    console.log('Resposne from mongo ', getUser);
    res.send(getUser);
  })
  .catch((err) =>
    res
      .status()
      .res.json(err, { message: "successfully fetched user by id " })
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi @Nitzy - I now have done a few more things to debug - the log shows null as you are right the id - I have added the id in my model as a string - that does not work, I have added it as an object as well that does not work.

Comment: you want to search via id or _id?

Comment: Hi @Nitzy the data created in mongoDB is  autogenerated as {"_id": "http://localhost:5000/api-users/5f494b4501e8411d7eb97492"} as an objectId When I go to the route  - http://localhost:5000/api-users/5f494b4501e8411d7eb97492  - on Postman there are no errors all the data comes back - so the original generic get call seems to be called first and not the id specific route. Delete works if I comment out the other routes. But then now, I have 2 data sets with the original POST route which worked and I set up 10 docs not working! I am not sure what the solution is although the problem seems clear.

Comment: I also tried ` module.exports = getUserById = (req, res) => {
    User.findById({ _id: req.params.userId }, { $set: req.body.userInfo })
      .exec()
      .then(function (getUser) {
        console.log("Response from mongo ", getUser);
        res.send(getUser);
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        res
          .status()
          .res.json(err, { message: "successfully fetched user by id " })
      );
  }; ` to set data and explicitly execute function - that didn't work

Comment: If  I comment out get and update endpoints delete works - not sure why. This is the put controller.   ```module.exports = updateUser = (req, res) => {
    //   .route("/api-users/:userId")
    User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.userId }, req.body, {
      new: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      omitUndefined: false,
    })
      .then(function (updatedUser) {
        res.send(updatedUser);
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        res
          .status()
          .res.json(err, { message: "successfully updated user by id " })
      );
  };```

Comment: how come you are getting complete URL in the _id field, check what you are sending while saving the data.
if possible please update the question with full code. that will be easy to answer any question

Comment: Hi @Nitzy I have edited and added more code on my question, I hope that helps - plus some of the other debug routes I have explored over the last couple of days...